# React webpack compile time oddities

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vagrant, sass-loader

We used create-react-app, to start this react project. We start the proj: npm start and it starts the server as normal.

Then we make a change to a .scss file and the first "compiling.." is fast ( sub 5 seconds )

However, every change after this is slower. To the point where it can take minutes.

Oddly this is only happening on 1 dev machine running via Vagrant on a Windows 10 machine. The rest of us, the project behaves normally ( same VagrantFile but a mixture of Mac and PC ). All the machines are similarly spec'd.

Has anyone ever experienced odd compiling times from react/webpack, and if so what direction could we go in to debug?

We have attempted to "eject" the react to access the webpack config to hopefully get better logs from the dev server, however, it doesn't seem possible to get the "compiling.." to print out what it's doing behind the scenes or what it's hanging on.

Any help appreciated, or any directions we can take to possibly start debugging would also be grateful.

Cheers

**Edit 1:**
We tried to wipe the system to make sure that it was not some sort of program causing issues, but this did not fix the issue. For now we ended up using another fresh machine, where the project worked as expected. So we believe the issue seems to be isolated to this one machine. Will continue to run more test on this laptop.